# Copy XML nodes from layout files of another action in Magento2

Tags: layout, magento2

My use case is, that I copied parts of the Magento checkout to the bundle's product's page. i.e. I copied parts from `app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml` to `app/design/frontend/Example/default/Magento_Bundle/layout/override/base/catalog_product_view_type_bundle.xml`. (which is used in `catalog_product_view` action)

But I also had to search in other `checkout_cart_index.xml` files for parts to copy. Especially the payment method renderers, as found for example in `app/code/Magento/Paypal/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`.

Is there a smarter way than copying this manually, for example by a layout  `<move>` statement? But I guess I can retrieve layout information from other actions? Is there a trick to do so?

Comment: I assume this is more than just calling another layout handle, but actually being selective in which parts you want to call right?

Answer (score 3):

[`<update>` instruction](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#fedg_layout_xml-instruc_ex_upd) is there to "copy" content of layout handles.

Comment: Thanks.but can I also select just some nodes or do I have to delete and move around the stuff I don't want?

Comment: You can not select nodes.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up in doing the following:

1. use `<update handle="checkout_index_index"/>` as suggested by Anton Kril to copy the full layout file (checkout_index_index to my layout)
2. Set `<referenceContainer name="page.messages" remove="false"/>` because there is a `<referenceContainer name="page.messages" remove="true"/>` in checkout_index_index which I do not want. The remaining part in checkout_index_index is just the `checkout.root` block.
3. I can now use a `<move>` to put the checkout block to the place where I need it
4. Use removeComponent=true to "clean up" the checkout. As in [Remove a UI component child via Layout XML](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109203/remove-a-ui-component-child-via-layout-xml)
5. I needed to change the Onepage block class -> did this via a DI rewrite

## Alternative Approach

My first approach was to manipulate the XML. This is possible by hooking to `\Magento\Framework\View\Layout::generateXml` and use DOMDocument to rewrite the generated XML.

As I found out that it is also possible with a combination of standard Magento 2 methods, I dumped this approach.