# Remove a UI component child via Layout XML

Tags: magento2, checkout, layout, uicomponent

How do I remove a UI component child via Layout XML?
For example, from the below xml directive in `checkout_index_index.xml`. How do I remove the shipping node ?

```
<item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="totals" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Subtotal</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="shipping" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Estimated Shipping</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="grand-total" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Estimated Total</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
```

The shipping node can be removed using plugin but I just thought there should be a be a better way like a **remove** node attribute.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

We can read the document here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_customize.html. In your case: we can apply this guide:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="totals" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <!--Remove fields-->
                                                        <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                        <item name="shipping" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                        <item name="grand-total" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

The result:

[image]

Read more here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/checkout/checkout_customize.html#disable-a-component

**[EDIT]**

Disable sidebar (Order summary) at checkout page.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a duplicate of https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/113151/31400.

I found that removing it using `componentDisabled` breaks the functionality.

You'd better off just removing the heading in the `shipping.phtml`.