# Magento 2 - Checkout - Payment methods not visible

Tags: magento2, layout, xml

I'm trying to extend checkout page, I copied the

> checkout_index_index.xml

in my layout folder (vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/layout) I change some thing in the file, now in the payment method I can't find method I set on the admin page. If I remove my custom layout file, the method come's back and they work's fine.

This'is my custom xml file (I remove jsLayout part I didn't modify it):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <css src="css/checkout.css" media="screen,projection" />
</head>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="page.messages" remove="true"/>
    <move element="logo" destination="top-header" before="header-links"/>
    <referenceContainer name="newsletternewsletter" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
        <action method="setPageTitle">
            <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Checkout</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <container name="checkout-container" as="checkout-container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="row no-margin">
            <container name="checkout-center" as="checkout-center" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col s12 m10 l10 offset-m1 offset-l1">
                <container name="checkout-border" as="checkout-border" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="dashboard-container">

                    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage" name="checkout.root" template="Magento_Checkout::onepage.phtml" cacheable="false">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                                <!-- NO CHANGE HERE -->
                            </argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>

                </container>
            </container>
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I saw many developers who did the same way. **We shouldn't try to override the layouts by copying them to our module or theme. And then, we modify them**.

In your case, we overridden "completely" the original layout. So, any changes will affect to the global layout node.

> Rather than copy extensive page layout or page configuration code and
>   then modify what you want to change, in the Magento system, you only
>   need to create an extending layout file that contains the changes you
>   want.

[Magento 2 Layout](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-overview.html)

Comment: You're right, if in my file I remove the block checkout.root and use the move attribute to put it where I want, the payment methods appear. But now I have the necessity to invert the order of some children inside the sidebar component, do you know any way to do it, without copy all the block? If I copy the block payment methods go way.

Comment: Read more here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133334/extension-attributes-to-add-product-attribute-to-the-order-summary-on-checkout/133732#133732 and http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109203/remove-a-ui-component-child-via-layout-xml/116415#116415

Comment: Could you write a simple example how to invert in sidebar component summary and cart-items children, I would like to set cart-items as first element and then summary element. I couldn't do it