# Magento 2: How can I use ifconfig or something similar to layout component

Tags: magento2, checkout, layout, di, component

I created a **boolean** option **(Yes / No)** in **Store -> Configuration**, with which I can display or not the checkout **sidebar**.

The configuration **path** is: `vendorname_sidebar/display/enabled`.

Below is a part about **sidebar** from the layout XML from `checkout_index_index.xml` of the Checkout module.

How do I show or not show the sidebar in checkout depending on this setting in **Store -> Configuration**?

```
<item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">50</item>
    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/sidebar</item>
    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">sidebar</item>
    ...
</item>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the answers to this question "[Remove a UI component child via Layout XML](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109203/remove-a-ui-component-child-via-layout-xml)" you can see how you can disable the sidebar UI component by XML. Now you do not want to do this this way, because then it would always be removed/disabled.

If you look at the complete layout XML in `checkout_index_index.xml`, it looks something like this:

```
<page ........>
  <body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
      <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage" name="checkout.root" template="onepage.phtml" cacheable="false">
        <arguments>
          <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="types" xsi:type="array">........</item>
            <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                ........
                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                  ........
                  <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">50</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/sidebar</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">sidebar</item>
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                      ........
                    </item>
                    ........
```

You see that the whole `<item ...>` XML is part of a bigger `<arguments>` structure that is a child of the `<block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage" ...>` definition. This whole structure is converted to a PHP associative array and passed into the `$data` argument of the constructor when creating this block class.

The `jsLayout` is a UI Components definition and you could disable the sidebar component by setting `componentDisabled` to `true` in the `config`.

If we look at the `Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage` constructor, we can see what happens to all this data. Also we see that there is an array argument `layoutProcessors`.

```
public function __construct(
    ........
    array $layoutProcessors = [],
    array $data = []
) {
    ........
    $this->jsLayout = isset($data['jsLayout']) && is_array($data['jsLayout']) ? $data['jsLayout'] : [];
    $this->layoutProcessors = $layoutProcessors;
}
```

Now the `jsLayout` is retreived from the Block by calling its `getJsLayout()` method which runs the layout processors first before returning the data as JSON:

```
public function getJsLayout()
{
    foreach ($this->layoutProcessors as $processor) {
        $this->jsLayout = $processor->process($this->jsLayout);
    }
    return \Zend_Json::encode($this->jsLayout);
}
```

So, you should also add a layout processor via Dependency Injection (DI) in your module's `etc/frontend/di.xml`:

```
<config ........>
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="layoutProcessors" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sidebarSwitcher" xsi:type="object">Vendorname\Sidebar\Block\CheckoutOnepage\SidebarSwitcherProcessor</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

This `\Vendorname\Sidebar\Block\CheckoutOnepage\SidebarSwitcherProcessor` class should implement `\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessorInterface` and (therefor) you should have a public method called `process()` where you can disable the sidebar based on the config you mention:

```
namespace Vendorname\Sidebar\Block\CheckoutOnepage;

use Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessorInterface;

class SidebarSwitcherProcessor implements LayoutProcessorInterface
{
    public function process($jsLayout) {
        if (..... check config value .....) {
            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['sidebar']['config']['componentDisabled'] = true;
        }
        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't works for me.

Comment: What did you try? Did you see if it reaches the process() method? (add logging or use xdebug)

Comment: You inspired me with your answer and I managed to do what I wanted, see my answer. Thanks

Comment: Your answer is very explicit. I gave you a vote.

Comment: It works perfectly for me ! @7ochem thank you for all the details and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

For use **Scope Config Interface** on the component from checkout page, you must create a **Plugin** see below:

Below code is must in `Vendorname/SidebarActivation/etc/frontend/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="SidebarDisable" type="Vendorname\SidebarActivation\Plugin\SidebarDisable"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Below code is in `Vendorname/SidebarActivation/Plugin/SidebarDisable.php`

```
<?php

namespace Vendorname\SidebarActivation\Plugin;

use Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor;

/**
 * Class SidebarDisable
 *
 * @package Vendorname\SidebarActivation\Plugin
 */
class SidebarDisable {

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $processor
     * @param array $jsLayout
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterProcess(
        LayoutProcessor $processor,
        array $jsLayout
    ){
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $enable = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('sectionid/groupid/fieldid');

        if($enable){
            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['sidebar']['config']['componentDisabled'] = true;
        }

        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. It is getting quite complex having a plugin on an object pool (layout processors) though, but still a good alternative. Also you shouldn't use the object manager, inject it in the constructor of your plugin instead.

Comment: I tried to put in the constructor but it does not work, it gives me the white page, I know it's good with the constructor but it does not work.

Comment: I am a big fan and I use the constructor.